# Exploding gradient for gpflow SVGP

Tags: gradient, gradient-descent, gpflow

When optimizing a SVGP with Poisson Likelihood for a big data set I see what I think are exploding gradients.
After a few epochs I see a spiky drop of the ELBO, which then very slowly recovers after getting rid of all progress made before.
Roughly 21 iterations correspond to an Epoch.

[image: ELBO]

This spike (at least the second one) resulted in a complete shift of the parameters (for vectors of parameters I just plotted the norm to see changes):
[image: Parameters]

How can I deal with that? My first approach would be to clip the gradient, but that seems to require digging around the gpflow code.

**My Setup:**

Training works via Natural Gradients for the variational parameters and ADAM for the rest, with a slowly (linearly) increasing schedule for the Natural Gradient Gamma.

The batch and inducing point sizes are as large as possible for my setup
(both 2^12, with the data set consisting of ~88k samples). I include 1e-5 jitter and initialize the inducing points with kmeans.

I use a combined kernel, consisting of a combination of RBF, Matern52, a periodic and a linear kernel on a total of 95 features (a lot of them due to a one-hot encoding), all learnable.
The lengthscales are transformed with gpflow.transforms.

```
    with gpflow.defer_build():
        k1 = Matern52(input_dim=len(kernel_idxs["coords"]), active_dims=kernel_idxs["coords"], ARD=False)
        k2 = Periodic(input_dim=len(kernel_idxs["wday"]), active_dims=kernel_idxs["wday"])
        k3 = Linear(input_dim=len(kernel_idxs["onehot"]), active_dims=kernel_idxs["onehot"], ARD=True)
        k4 = RBF(input_dim=len(kernel_idxs["rest"]), active_dims=kernel_idxs["rest"], ARD=True)
        #
        k1.lengthscales.transform = gpflow.transforms.Exp()
        k2.lengthscales.transform = gpflow.transforms.Exp()
        k3.variance.transform = gpflow.transforms.Exp()
        k4.lengthscales.transform = gpflow.transforms.Exp()

        m = gpflow.models.SVGP(X, Y, k1 + k2 + k3 + k4, gpflow.likelihoods.Poisson(), Z,
                               mean_function=gpflow.mean_functions.Constant(c=np.ones(1)),
                               minibatch_size=MB_SIZE, name=NAME)
        m.mean_function.set_trainable(False)

    m.compile()
```

**UPDATE: Using only ADAM**
Following the suggestion by Mark, I switched to ADAM only,
which helped me get rid of that sudden explosion. However, I still initialized with an epoch of natgrad only, which seems to save a lot of time.

[image: Comparison of ADAM+NATGRAD(grey) vs ADAM only(red)]

In addition, the variational parameters seem to change a lot less abrupt (in terms of their norm at least). I guess they'll converge way slower now, but at least it's stable.
[image: Comparison of ADAM+NATGRAD(grey) vs ADAM only(red)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very interesting. Perhaps trying to not use natgrads is a good idea as well. Clipping gradients indeed seems like a hack that could work. And yes, this would require digging around in the GPflow code a bit. One tip that can help towards this, is by not using the GPflow optimisers directly. The `model._likelihood_tensor` contains the TF tensor that should be optimised. Perhaps with some manual TensorFlow magic, you can do the gradient clipping on here before running an optimiser.

In general, I think this sounds like you've stumbled on an actual research problem. Usually these large gradients have a good reason in the model, which can be addressed with careful thought. Is it variance in some monte carlo estimate? Is the objective function behaving badly?

Regarding why not using natural gradients helps. Natural gradients use the Fisher matrix as a preconditioner to perform second order optimisation.  Doing so can result in quite aggressive moves in parameter space. In certain cases (when there are usable conjugacy relations) these aggressive moves can make optimisation much faster. This case, with the Poisson likelihood, is not one where there are conjugacy relations that will necessarily help optimisation. In fact, the Fisher preconditioner can often be detrimental, particularly when variational parameters are not near the optimum.

Comment: Using ADAM worked, although don't understand why..

Thank you

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on your intuition about not using the natgrads?

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Mark's answer above, when using nat grads in non-conjugate models it can take a bit of tuning to get the best performance, and instability is potentially a problem. As Mark points out, the large steps that provide potentially faster convergence can also lead to the parameters ending up in in bad regions of the parameter space. When the variational approximation is good (i.e. the true and approximate posterior are close) then there is good reason to expect that the nat grad will perform well, but unfortunately there is no silver bullet in the general case. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.02984 for some intuition.

Comment: Thanks, that does kinda make sense. Though it's kinda curious that this does not occur at the beginning, when I only use natgrad alone as an initialization.  I would have suspected that at the beginning they are furthest away.

Also thanks in general for replying so quickly, really appreciate it.